there are $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $(a, b)$ such that $ f^{\prime}\left(x_1\right)<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}<f^{\prime}\left(x_2\right) $

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$. Prove that if $f$ is not a linear function, then there are $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $(a, b)$ such that
$$
f^{\prime}\left(x_1\right)<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}<f^{\prime}\left(x_2\right)
$$


The following solution was shown in the book:

Since $f$ is not a linear function, there is $c \in(a, b)$ such that $f(c)<f(a)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(c-a)$ or $f(c)>f(a)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(c-a)$.
Suppose, for example, that$$
f(c)<f(a)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(c-a)
$$Then$$
\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \text { and } \frac{f(c)-f(b)}{c-b}>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} .
$$Consequently, the assertion follows from the mean value theorem. Analogous reasoning can be applied to the case where
$$
f(c)>f(a)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(c-a)
$$


I understand till $\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$
but how do they assert that for that point $c$, the next inequality, that is $$\frac{f(c)-f(b)}{c-b}>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$ also holds? The reason isn't clear to me, why can't $$\frac{f(c)-f(b)}{c-b}\leq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$?

Please let me know if you are satisfied with this answer

Your textbook if wrong, also because
$$\frac{f(c)-f(b)}{c-b}>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
would not led to the thesis. The correct inequality is
$$\frac{f(b)-f(c)}{b-c}>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a},$$
which can be easily proved:
$$\frac{f(b)-f(c)}{b-c}>\frac{f(b)-f(a)-(c-a)\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}}{b-c}$$
The second term corresponds to
$$\frac{(b-a)(f(b)-f(a))-(c-a)(f(b)-f(a))}{(b-a)(b-c)}$$
i.e.
$$\frac{(b-c)(f(b)-f(a))}{(b-a)(b-c)}=\frac{(f(b)-f(a))}{(b-a)}$$
